# Flash Animations are horizontally crunched and colors are bogus

Tags: firefox, video, flash

On a fresh install, I cannot read flash animations properly.

I tried enabling `hwaccel` and `gpuoverride` using `mms.cfg` which didn't change anything.

Video playback in VLC is OK.

**My graphics chip** :
Intel Corporation 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE Chipset Integrated Graphics Device (rev 01)

This is how it is looks like :

[image]

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing/reinstalling the Adobe Flash plugin?
try:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge flashplugin-installer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: I have already tried that unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Go and install 10.04 then all the new issues won't affect you 
Had the excact same issue when installing 12.04 could not solve and watch flash streaming vids until I downgraded now everything works fine just have to not ever update

Comment: Downgrading isn't a solution